# Yaml script to find the given file is empty or not

Tags: ansible

Can anyone please help with ansible yaml script to find the given file is empty or not.

Basically, the file path will be predefined and below is my script.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
          - name: "to check file is empty or not"
            file: path=/home/ubuntu/siva state=file
          - file: state=empty
            register: emptyfile
          - debug:
                  msg: "{% if emptyfile == true %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}"
```

After running script i am getting {"changed": false, "msg": "missing required arguments: path"} error

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your new information. Essential information does not belong in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `file` module twice ... and in the second `file` usage you are not giving a path. This parameter is required which the error message states.

Apart from that I do not think your second `file` will work at all, the parameter `state` does not have the option **empty** (see [file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html) documentation).